# if image and url contain the same word, can I add a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, url

I have an interesting idea, but maybe (or rather hopefully) it isn't new to you.

I have an image-based menu on a homepage. That is, hundreds of images. When the user has browsed to a certain URL, and then opens the dropdown again (containing the images) I want the URLs image to have a frame.

For example, the user is on my-homepage.com/flowers and the image "#flowers" gets a frame from a class.

I know I can do this which works great:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  if(/my-url/.test(loc)) {
    jQuery('#my-image').addClass('active-image-url');
  }
});

.active-image-url {border: 1px solid #000;}
```

But then again, I have hundreds of images, so it would be quite crazy to add that code a hundred times.
Isn't there a way to compare URL and image ID and if these are the same, the class gets added? For example, if a part of the URL my-homepage.com/flowers partly equals  "#flowers" please add class.

I know it is not like this, but for the sake of explaining well:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  if(/flowers/.test(loc)) {
    jQuery('#flowers').addClass('active-image-url');
  }
});
```

What do you think, could it be done? Maybe it's a JavaScript task?

Best regards,
Skt

Comment: Sure, though it would make more sense for a backend to handle it. And will the URL always be the same structure, for example: `https://example.com/flowers`?

Comment: As a side remark, as such, having a menu built with hundreds of images is probably a very bad idea for performance, accessibility, maintenance,...

Comment: I exaggerated with the numbers of images. They are rather max. 50 or so. Still many, but managable. 
I would go for short URLs like example.com/flowers but I guess one could try to catch the last string? But I guess one searches from the left, so that wouldn't work perhaps.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what is to be matched in the URL. You mention 'part of' the URL, does that mean any part or is it just the final part? And is it all the id that you want to match and is it to match the whole of a part of the URL?

Comment: It could be a URL with several strings, but not necessarily. I'd adapt it in order to get the idea to work.

Comment: So, I would name the IDs to match the URL. If my URL is www.site.com/lamps/shade1, I would give the image (which links to that URL) the ID #shade1.

Comment: But if that double-string URL doesn't work, I'd change to ...com/shade1. So the idea is that the user should know where he or she is when opening when opening the menu. The menu is embedded in the same page, always.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the path of the URL or the href like you did, split the string by '/' into an array, and use the last element of the array to query for an HTML element. Something like this:

```
const path = window.location.pathname;

const words = path.split('/');

jQuery(`#${word[words.length - 1]}`).addClass('active-image-url');
```

Comment: wow, this looks great. But it doesn't work for me for some reason. Is it searching the whole URL?

Comment: pathname takes whatever is after the host, in your example, "my-homepage.com/flowers" is the href, "my-homepage.com" is the host, and "/flowers" is the path. Try taking the entire href. It should still work the same. I tried it using 'getElementById" instead of jQuery.

Comment: getElementByID sounds like a promising strategy. I started writing it now but realised I lack skills for that. If you could help me out it would be great!

Comment: I would love to help you out but I am not sure how. getElementById is easy to use. It just finds the first HTML element with the id given as the argument, similar to how you used jQuery. In this case the statement would become ```getElementById(`${word[words.length - 1]}`).addClass('active-image-url');``` Notice that the # sign is not included. You could also try googling examples if you get stuck.

Comment: Also, make sure to check if the query string is working as expected. Try logging the path variable and the words array and check if the last element in the words array is the id you want to query.

Comment: Isnt it better to use `const word = path.split('/').pop();` ? then you have the same result of `words[words.length - 1]` in `word`

Comment: hmm. I can't get it to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try console logging to check if the variables are assigned as expected?

Comment: I read about console logging but I need more time to understand how it works...

Comment: just add ```console.log(path, word);``` after you assign both and you can see the values in the browser's console.